# difference between glTextureBarrier() and glMemoryBarrier(GL_TEXTURE_FETCH_BARRIER_BIT)

Tags: opengl, memory, opengl-es, render-to-texture

glMemoryBarrier is available in GL 4.2 and higher while glTextureBarrier is available in GL 4.5

glTextureBarrier allows to simultaneously render into the same texture while the fragment shader is fetching from it, IFF every texel of the texture is hit by the texturefetches exactly once.

I wonder whether glMemoryBarrier(GL_TEXTURE_FETCH_BARRIER_BIT) allows this too? If not, is there an OpenGL ES equivalent to glTextureBarrier?

Answer (score 4):

> glTextureBarrier allows to simultaneously render into the same texture while the fragment shader is fetching from it, IFF every texel of the texture is hit by the texturefetches exactly once.

No, it doesn't.

`glTextureBarrier` is a function. ARB_texture_barrier is an extension (and part of GL 4.5). As part of the changes to the specification, the ARB_texture_barrier extension permits a single read/modify/write over an attached image.

Now, calling `glTextureBarrier` will permit you a *second* read/modify/write pass. And you can call it again to get another pass. But `glTextureBarrier` itself is not what gives you read/modify/write privileges. It's the extension as a whole.

Also, note that these two functions have nothing in common.

`glMemoryBarrier(GL_TEXTURE_FETCH_BARRIER_BIT)` only applies to writes by [incoherent memory operations](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Incoherent_Memory_Access) (SSBOs/image load/store). That particular barrier bit means that incoherent writes issued before this function will become visible to texture sample operations issued after this function.

`glTextureBarrier` applies specifically to writes to framebuffer attached images and subsequent reads from them in the shader. Framebuffer writes are not incoherent memory operations, and thus they are not governed by the `glMemoryBarrier` call.

> If not, is there an OpenGL ES equivalent to glTextureBarrier?

Not as of yet. And considering the kind of hardware that tends to implement ES, it's unlikely to ever get there. While the general idea has merit for tile-based renderers, it's just the wrong abstraction for them.

Vulkan's input attachments and pipeline barriers are a much better fit for doing this sort of thing in a TBR.

Comment: Does that mean if the texture_barrier extension is available, I can render an object into an FBO and then render a full-screen quad to the same FBO with a fragment shader that fetches the color attachment of this FBO as texture (gl_FragCoord.xy) to implement a fullscreen effect, and I don't need to call glTextureBarrier before drawing the full-screen quad? Or do I need glTextureBarrier already in this case?

Comment: Also, what exactly means a single "read/modify/write pass" ? if the texture is a multi-sample texture, is it allowed to read all samples of the source texel or would that not be considered a single read?